# How do you pronounce a Qur'an citation?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce a Qur'an citation like:

> Qur’an 4:15–16

Would you say: Qur'an Chapter 4 Verses 15 and 16?

Answer (score 1):

You can say

> Quran Chapter 4, Aayahs 15-16

or

> Quran Surah An-Nisa, Aayah 15-16

or

> One of the above and then recite the two Aayahs.

*Additions:*
OP asked about the following too:

**Surah An-Nisa** is the fourth Surah in Quran.

**Aayah** is the smallest unit in Quran. It can be a two or more letters, a word, a phrase, a sentence, or many sentences. There is not any term in grammar or linguistics which match to an aayah. This concept is unique to Quran.

Comment: No, I mean how to *say* it. Do you have to pronounce Arabic exactly? Is there an English equivalent?

Comment: I revised the entire answer. Let me know if that's what you mean.

Comment: OK! Thanks! That's what I meant. Now, what does "Surah An-Nisa" mean and what does "Aayah" mean?

Comment: Surah An-Nisa is the fourth Surah in Quran. Aayah is the smallest unit in Quran. It can be a two or more letters, a word, a phrase, a sentence, or many sentences. There is not any term in grammar or linguistics which match to an aayah. This concept is unique to Quran.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. The term "Verse" is used for Bible. So many people use Verse to mention an Aayah. This is not exactly correct. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Whoever downvoted it, please explain.

Comment: The downvotes have been removed. The question has been moved to a more appropriate SE site.